# Gallery opens itself on ZenPad10 while the screen is off

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, tablet, gallery

I've got myself an Asus ZenPad 10 (model P023) last year, and I'm more than happy with it but there is one small issue I have with it: sometimes, while the screen is off, the Gallery app launches itself and wakes the screen up.

While not particularly a hinder, I haven't been able to reliably reproduce it; it usually happens when I put the tablet down, but not always. I know that I can double-tap on the screen to wake it up (which is a great feature), but that's about it. I have tried to swipe the screen in various directions, and tapping more than twice, each with more than one finger too, to no avail.

Note that although I'd like to know how to stop it from happening, I'm mostly curious about how it happens.

The Android version running on this is 5.0.2, Gallery version is 1.5.0.150826_3_PROJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with some options earlier, I actually came accross the answer on accident. This is from a feature called ZenMotion, something ASUS started implementing in their Zen phones and tablets, I believe.

[image: The Touch Gesture feature of ZenMotion]

Note that not only this answered my question, it also showed me that there were 5 other shortcuts available, with each letter being able to be linked to a different app if I chose so.